# Navigation drawer with diff fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

I am using android default navigation drawer and i want that same layout for all the activities i tried searching on internet i got some ideas for customized drawer but not on android studio default drawer. Kindly help me.

navigation drawer.class :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) 
    findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", 
    Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
    R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
    findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

app_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout     
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

app_bar_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.spykid.navig.navig_sample.Main2Activity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here in app_bar_main layout i would like to change that 
include layout="@layout/content_main" with my activity or fragment so that i can have the same layout.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: question seems to be confusing bro

Comment: i just need a way to have same navigation drawer if i create a new activity

Comment: Hey try this link[http://androhub.com/android-navigationdrawer/] for Custom Navigation drawer.

Comment: that url says page not found.......and i am looking if i can edit default navigation drawer which is provided by android sdk not customizeed one.........anyways thanks for the info surender kumar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an Activity containing only `NavigationDrawer` and after that `OnItemSelected` from `NavigationDrawer` call every activity you want. Then `NavigationDrawer` will be available in all the activities.

The other solution is create `MainActivity` with `NavigationDrawer` and create other `Fragments` instead of `Activities`. Call those `Fragmnets` `OnItemSelected` from `NavigationDrawer`. There are alot of example available there.

**Edit**

In your activity where you have defined navigationDrawer, do the following. And instead of creating new activities for next layouts, create fragments and call them on OnItemSelected on navigationDrawer like below:

```
 navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {


                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
                else menuItem.setChecked(true);

                //Closing drawer on item click
                drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {


                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.drawer_home:

                        Intent intent=new Intent(HomeActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
                        finish();
                        return true;

                    // For rest of the options we just show a toast on click

                    case R.id.drawer_artist:

                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager=getSupportFragmentManager();
                        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new ArtistsFragment());
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        return true;


                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Somethings Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return true;

                }
            }
        });
```

Fragment code will be like:

```
public class ArtistsFragment extends Fragment {

    public ArtistsFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootview= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_artists, container, false);

        return  rootview;
    }}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >
        <include
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/home">


            <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="match_parent"
                          android:orientation="vertical"

                >



</LinearLayout>


        </FrameLayout>



    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_all"
        app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
        app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
        app:theme="@style/list_item_appearance"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" >


    </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: if i call my activity from onItemselected via intent startactivity i am not getting navigation drawer

Comment: @Nikhil- have you put your navigation drawer in separate activity? If you are getting confused, y don't you try for fragments?

Comment: @Nikhil if you want i can provide you whole code for that.

Comment: i am not using fragments i am just accessing it as an activity............send me a sample for it my mai lid nikhilpnkr@gmail.com........thanks in advance

Comment: @Nikhil check for the edit. If you get any problem tell me. thanks.

Comment: @geek i have done that before and i was not able to set that id in  fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, new ArtistsFragment());......i was not able to assign that id correctly can you put your xml files where i can find out how to initialize that id

Comment: I followed your code and i am replacing my fragment if itemselected but its not workingFragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            AboutUs hello = new AboutUs();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, hello, "HELLO");
            fragmentTransaction.commit();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108025/discussion-between-nikhil-and-android-geek).